# Codility - min average slice

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dynamic-programming, kadanes-algorithm

I'm trying to find a solution to [a codility question on minimum slice of a subarray](https://codility.com/demo/results/demoWMFFEK-WMR/), and I've devised a solution using a modified version of Kadane's algorithm. I've currently gotten 90/100 and managed to pass almost all the tests in O(n). However, I can't seem to pass "medium_range, increasing, decreasing (legth = ~100) and small functional, got 5 expected 3", and I have no idea why. This is possibly a repeat of [solution](http://codesays.com/2014/solution-to-min-avg-two-slice-by-codility/), but I'm using a slightly different way of solving.

My logic is as follows:

a) if we have an array MinA where MinA[k] represents the minimum average slice of a subarray starting from k with minimum length of 2

b) then if we loop through MinA and find the minimum of the array, then this will be the minimum average slice for the whole array (and then return the index position)

c) to create this MinA, we start from the second last element of the array and MinA[A.length -2] is the average of the last two elements of A

d) we move the counter one position to the left; MinA[counter] will have to be either average of A[counter] and A[counter + 1] or the average of the elements counter and the elements in MinA[counter + 1]

e) if d was not true, then this implies that MinA[counter + 1] is not the minimal average slice from counter + 1 to some element from counter + 2 to N

I wonder if I'm missing something?

```
/*
 * Using modified version of Kadane's algorithm
 * The key logic is that for an array A of length N, 
 * if M[k + 1] is the minimum slice of a subarray from k + 1 to any element
 * between k+2 to n, then M[k] is either the average of A[k] and A[k + 1], or
 * the average of the elements k and the elements in M[k + 1]
 */
function solution(A) {
    // you can use console.log for debugging purposes, i.e.
    // console.log('this is debug message');
    // write your code in JavaScript (ECMA-262, 5th edition)
    var minSliceArray = [],
        counter = A.length - 2,
        currMinSliceLength = 0,
        min = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
        minIndex = -1;

    minSliceArray[counter] = (A[counter] + A[counter + 1]) / 2;
    currMinSliceLength = 2;
    counter--;

    while (counter >= 0) {
        var a = (A[counter] + A[counter + 1]) / 2,
            b = (A[counter] + minSliceArray[counter + 1] * currMinSliceLength) / (currMinSliceLength + 1) ;
        if (a < b) {
            minSliceArray[counter] = a;
            currMinSliceLength = 2;
        } else {
            minSliceArray[counter] = b;
            currMinSliceLength++;
        }
        counter--;
    }

    //loops through the minSliceArray and find the minimum slice
    for (var i = 0; i < minSliceArray.length; i++) {
        if (minSliceArray[i] < min) {
            min = minSliceArray[i];
            minIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return minIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix your problem, you could replace the code

```
if (a < b) {
```

with

```
if (a <= b) {
```

For example A = [-3, 3, -3, 3, -3], firstly, we are considering the A[3:5], and the average is 0. Then, we  come to position 2, A[2:5]/3 = -1, and A[2:4]/2 = 0. So we choose the former. For position 1, A[1:3]/2 == A[1:5]/4 == 0. In **OLD** answer, we should continue to choose A[1:5]. Finally for position 0, we have A[0:2]/2 = 0, and A[0:5]/5 = -0.6 And we choose the later. After all, the overall minimual average is at position 3 as A[3:5]/3=-1. **BUT** actually A[0:3]/3 == -1 == A[3:5]/3.

Because of such traps, I did not use the modified version of Kadane's algorithm in my blog. But it should work well.

Answer (score 1):

On the [first attempt](https://codility.com/demo/results/trainingHK4NAX-WV2/) of this, I had a O(2<sup>N</sup>N) algorithm, that was easy but got only 40% correctness and 0% performance:

```
function solution(A) {
    var m = null, c, n
    for ( var i = 0; i < A.length; ++i ) {
        for ( var j = i + 1; j <= A.length; ++j ) {
            c = A.slice(i, j + 1).reduce(function (a,b) { return a+b }) / (j - i + 1)
            if ( m === null || c < m ) {
                m = c
                n = i
            }
            else if ( c == m && i < n ) {
                n = i
            }
        }
    }
    return n
}
```

Slept on it and came up with this for the [second attempt](https://codility.com/demo/results/training5MPJ2U-FMA/), got a O(N) algorithm, that got 100% correctness and 100% performance:

```
function solution(A) {
    if ( A.length < 2 )  return -1
    var result = A.reduce(function (a, b, bIndex) {
        var f = typeof a === 'number'
        var x, y, z
        z = {
            index: bIndex,
            value: b,
            couple: {
                start: bIndex - 1,
                sum:   x = (f ? a : a.value) + b,
                count: 2,
                avg:   x / 2
            },
            streak: {
                start: a.bestStreak ? a.bestStreak.start : 0,
                sum:   x = (f ? a : a.bestStreak.sum) + b,
                count: y = (f ? 1 : a.bestStreak.count) + 1,
                avg:   x / y
            }
        }

        z.bestStreak = z.couple.avg < z.streak.avg
            ? z.couple
            : z.streak

        z.best = !a.best || z.bestStreak.avg < a.best.avg
            ? z.bestStreak
            : a.best

        // console.log(JSON.stringify({z}, null, '  '))

        return z
    })
    return result.best.start
}
```

After solving it, I looked around to see how others have done it. IMHO my above solution is the easiest to understand and debug.

It works by knowing that no streak's average can become lower, if that streak does not contain a lower streak within itself.

This may seem odd, as you may be like - well what happens if I have an average streak, and then a super low number. Well the highest number in that streak is never the last number, as that would increase the average of the streak, breaking it. So the last number, is either a number beneficial to a streak, in which case the next number may be beneficial too, and may form a couple that is a better streak, or the last or current number are streak breakers and can be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

How about

Javascript

```
function solution(A) {
    var minpos = 0,
        minavg = (A[0] + A[1]) / 2,
        N = A.length,
        N1 = N - 1,
        N2 = N - 2,
        sumTwo,
        t,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < N2; i += 1) {
        sumTwo = A[i] + A[i + 1];
        t = sumTwo / 2;
        if (minavg > t) {
            minavg = t;
            minpos = i;
        }

        t = (sumTwo + A[i + 2]) / 3;
        if (minavg > t) {
            minavg = t;
            minpos = i;
        }

    }

    t = (A[N2] + A[N1]) / 2;
    if (minavg > t) {
        minavg = t;
        minpos = N2;
    }

    return minpos;
}

var A = [4, 2, 2, 5, 1, 5, 8];

console.log(solution(A));
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Hveu8/)

Comment: Hmmm, it says that it's N^2 complexity (https://codility.com/demo/results/demo6EV4HH-C36/)

Comment: Sorry, full of flu, the kids too. I seriously misread and overcomplicated things. Is this any better, or have I still misunderstood the problem? Sorry if I have, really thick head just now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Although Sheng's correction does help, the algorithm still does not work in all cases.
For instance, the algorithm returns `2` for `[-18, 65, -11, 73, -22, 90, 21, 10, 47, 87]`. Expected value is `0`.

### Possible Cause:

Consider an intermediate step of the algorithm. If A[i..j] has minimum average for slices starting with i, then to include element at i-1, only these options are considered:

- A[i-1...j]
- A[i-1...i]

Unfortunately, there could exist an index `k` such that `avg(A[i...k]) > avg(A[i...j])`, but `avg(A[i-1...k]) < avg(A[i-1...j])`. Although this can be proven mathematically, a single example should suffice here.

`[-18, 65, -11, 73, -22, 90, 21, 10, 47, 87]
avg([65, -11, 73, -22]) = 26.25
avg([65, -11]) = 27       // This is ignored as avg is higher`

In order to include -18, the algorithm considers `[-18, 65, -11, 73, -22]` and `[-18, 65]`.

`avg([-18, 65, -11, 73, -22]) = 17.4
avg([-18, 65]) = 23.5
avg([-18, 65, -11]) = 12   // True minimum which is not considered`

I had submitted a similar solution and it scored 100% in Codelity. However, it isn't the correct solution.

Comment: I tried my own C++ implementation, based on Sheng's principle but on his code. The result of the above data is 0.

Answer (score 0):

In the other post I provide an extensive description of my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52616898/4281529). I'm not including it here because you already have the idea.

```
int solution(vector<int> &A) {

    // Find prefix sum.
    int N = A.size();
    vector<int> ps(N + 1, 0);

    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        ps[i] = A[i - 1] + ps[i - 1];
    }

    int lft_idx, min_lft_idx;
    double avg_here, min_avg, avg_of_two, avg_with_prev;

    // Initialize variables at the first possible slice (A[0:1]).
    lft_idx = min_lft_idx = 0;
    avg_here = min_avg = (A[0] + A[1]) / 2.0;

    // Find min average of every slice that ends at ith element,
    // starting at i = 2.
    for (int i = 2; i < N; i ++) {

        // average of A[lft_idx : i]
        avg_with_prev = ((double) ps[i + 1] - ps[lft_idx]) / 
                        (i - lft_idx + 1);

        // average of A[i - 1 : i]
        avg_of_two = (A[i - 1] + A[i]) / 2.0;

        // Find minimum and update lft_idx of slice
        // (previous lft_idx or i - 1).
        if (avg_of_two < avg_with_prev) {
            avg_here = avg_of_two;
            lft_idx = i - 1;
        }
        else
            avg_here = avg_with_prev;

        // Keep track of minimum so far and its left index.
        if (avg_here < min_avg) {
            min_avg = avg_here;
            min_lft_idx = lft_idx;
        }
    }

    return min_lft_idx;
}
```

It achieved 100% on Codility, and also gives the right answer to the example of @Manas Chaudhari.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [Sheng's great solution](http://codesays.com/2014/solution-to-min-avg-two-slice-by-codility/), I wrote the following proof:

Assume you found the slice with minimal average. Assume the first two consecutive elements of the slice have higher average. If you take out (any) elements with higher average from the (or any) slice, then your reduced slice now has lower average (This is intuitive but should be proven. See proof below). Thus, having first two consecutive elements with higher average (to take out) contradicts the initial assumption that you found the slice with minimal average.

Intermediate conclusion:
As long as you can take out two consecutive first elements, then either their average is lower or equal to the slice's, or the reduced slice's average is lower, which contradicts the initial assumption that you found the slice with minimal average.
It is given that a slice must contain at least 2 elements. Thus, a slice from which you can take out first two consecutive elements has more than three elements. Hence,

Conclusion:
For any slice with the minimal average, it is either of size 3, or there is a slice of size 2 with that minimal average.

S0 = (a0+a1+a2+…an)/n 
S1 = (a2+…an)/(n-2)
S2 = (a0+a1)/2
==> S2 = ((n)S0-(n-2)S1)/2
S2 > S0 ==>  ((n)S0-(n-2)S1)/2 > S0  ==> S1 < S0.